# QTreeView item editor: how to make it only commit the edit on Enter press?

Tags: qt, qtreeview

By default, the editor commits the data on Enter press, Tab press or focus change. I need to discard edits on focus change or Tab press instead of committing them to the model. How do I do that? I already have my own delegate class, can I do it with its help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at what is going on for base class :

$QT482DIR/src/gui/itemviews/qitemdelegate.cpp

```
bool QItemDelegate::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
```

And overload this method to change the default behaviour. Just taking a look at it, I would follow `commitData()` and `closeEditor()` calls. As well as `_q_commitDataAndCloseEditor` to see what's going on

Comment: I've looked into it, and it seems to me that all the interesting stuff happens in the private class, which I can't alter by overriding the public interface.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe you can ovverride a lot of things via event filter

Comment: @DmitrySazonov: you're right. I can't reproduce the whole functionality of the default filter since it uses private stuff, but I can still solve my problem.